# ¿se adapta este codigo a todos los tamaños de pantalla planteados por el grid de boostrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                    <div  class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" >
                    header
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-1">
                    nav
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-xl-10">
                    main
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-1">
                    aside
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    footer
                    </div >
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sí, en la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) están todos los tamaños

- .col-    Extra small <576px
- .col-sm-Small       ≥576px
- .col-md-  Medium      ≥768px
- .col-lg- Large       ≥992px
- .col-xl-Extra large ≥1200px